# R: Replacing values in a data frame column with a more descriptive value

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on an R project and I have the following data frame with the columns 'key' and 'activity':

activities:

```
  key           activity
1   1            WALKING
2   2   WALKING_UPSTAIRS
3   3 WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS
4   4            SITTING
5   5           STANDING
6   6             LAYING
```

I also have another data frame with the columns 'subject' and 'activity_label':

new_data:

```
 subject activity_label 
1       1              2        
2       1              5        
3       1              3         
4       1              5        
5       1              4         
6       1              1
```

For the above data frame I want to replace the values in the 'activity_label' column with the corresponding activity description in the 'activities' data frame. For example the activity label 1 has the corresponding description of WALKING, activity label 2 has the description of WALKING_UPSTAIRS, etc.

However, I am not sure what would be the best way to do this. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like `merge()` or `dplyr::inner_join()` using (key, activity_label) would solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` :

```
activities$activity[match(new_data$activity_label, activities$key)]

#[1] "WALKING_UPSTAIRS"   "STANDING"           "WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS"
#[4] "STANDING"           "SITTING"            "WALKING"
```

Or perhaps `merge` and remove the unwanted column.

```
merge(new_data, activities, by.x = 'activity_label', by.y = 'key')
```

Using `dplyr`

```
dplyr::inner_join(new_data, activities, by = c('activity_label' = 'key'))


#  subject activity_label           activity
#1       1              2   WALKING_UPSTAIRS
#2       1              5           STANDING
#3       1              3 WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS
#4       1              5           STANDING
#5       1              4            SITTING
#6       1              1            WALKING
```

Answer (score 1):

As your `activities` are already *sorted* and have *no gap* you can use the number in `activity_label` direct as an *index* to get the activity.

```
activities$activity[new_data$activity_label]
#[1] "WALKING_UPSTAIRS"   "STANDING"           "WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS"
#[4] "STANDING"           "SITTING"            "WALKING"
```

In case activities are not sorted and have gaps you can make a lookup table and use this to get the activities from the numbers:

```
activity <- "[<-"(NA, activities$key, activities$activity)
activity[new_data$activity_label]
#[1] "WALKING_UPSTAIRS"   "STANDING"           "WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS"
#[4] "STANDING"           "SITTING"            "WALKING"
```

Data:

```
activities <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="  key           activity
1   1            WALKING
2   2   WALKING_UPSTAIRS
3   3 WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS
4   4            SITTING
5   5           STANDING
6   6             LAYING")

new_data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=" subject activity_label 
1       1              2        
2       1              5        
3       1              3         
4       1              5        
5       1              4         
6       1              1")
```